# An approximation of $\sqrt{1 + x}$ or $\sqrt{x}$ with connections to combinatorics or random walk?

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion, approximation, random-walk

I am looking for an approximation of $\sqrt{1 + x}$ or $\sqrt{x}$.

We know $\sqrt{1 + x}$  has a Taylor expansion:

${\displaystyle {\sqrt {1+x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}(2n)!}{(1-2n)(n!)^{2}(4^{n})}}x^{n}=1+{\frac {1}{2}}x-{\frac {1}{8}}x^{2}+{\frac {1}{16}}x^{3}-{\frac {5}{128}}x^{4}+\cdots ,}$

But for the problem I am working on, (a problem in random walk), I would like to get an alternative approximation of $\sqrt{1 + x}$ or $\sqrt{x}$, and hope it has some natural connections to combinatorics or probability or random walk.

Is there an approximation of $\sqrt{1 + x}$ or $\sqrt{x}$ which has some connections to combinatorics or probability or random walk ?

Comment: The generating function for the Catalan numbers is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n x^n = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$; does that help?

Comment: @JairTaylor Thank you.  I need an approximation of $\sqrt{1 + x}$, would it be possible somehow to "mutate" Catalan number, to have another "combinatorial process" to have  $\sqrt{1 + x}$ ?

Comment: What kind of approximation are you looking for?  The Taylor series you quote is unique, but you can also find rational approximations, continued fractions, etc.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you. Does rational approximations, continued fraction approximation have any "combinatorial interpretation" ?

Comment: @david Sure, you can just substitute $-1/4 x$ for $x$ and solve for $\sqrt{1+x}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor, thank you. I see, so $\sqrt{1+x}$ will be some mixing of $C_n$.

Comment: @JairTaylor, Does $\log(1+x)$ also have connection with Catalan numbers or any other combinatorics or random walk similar to $\sqrt{1 + x }$ ?

Comment: @david $\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}x^n$, or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!\frac{x^n}{n!}x^n$ as an exponential generating function, so you can use your favorite combinatorial interpretation for $(n-1)!$.  For example, it is the number of permutations on $n-1$ elements, the number of cyclic permutations of $n$ elements, or the number of "increasing trees" on $n$ elements (labeled trees where the labels increase as you go "down" from the root.)

Comment: @JairTaylor, thank you again. We know that $\exp(-x^2)$ is the limit of the distribution of binomial random walk. Is $\log(1 + x)$ and $\sqrt{1 + x}$ the limit of the distribution of other (maybe "restricted") random walks or combinatorics process ?

Comment: @david Those functions do not have a finite integral so they can't be density functions unless they're over some restricted interval.  I don't know of any such connection.

Comment: @JairTaylor, thank you for point out the finite integral restriction.

Comment: @david If you know how to code, you can always simulate random walks of various types for yourself and then formulate conjectures.  It's good fun.

Comment: @JairTaylor, I will try to simulate random walks per your suggestion.